# ASPX page address IF statement

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I'm trying to figure out how to create an aspx page that onload, checks the address, and if it contains a word (i.e 'Test' or 'Live) then to do different things, namely, load a different CSS file.

Any help would be apprecaited.

Thank you

D

Comment: Look into `Request.Uri` and `Request.RawUrl`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bit of a duplicate to me:
[Get PageName.aspx from Page object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834802/get-pagename-aspx-from-page-object)
(Discalimer: comments dont work for me at the moment.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can get as far as retriving the URI, assigning that value to a variable, but the 'Contains' part of the IF fails. Even if I hard code a value, the If still runs to the ELSE. Will Contains not work if the parameter is flanked by slashes? (i.e. \test\)

Comment: can you show the contains code please. Just edit your question. Hey! Coments work for me now!

Comment: I've just got the contains to work, it doesnt like ToLower() though. I've got the IF working too, now I just need to direct it to the different CSS files..

Answer (score 0):

For example, your url is: `http://test.be?css=Test`

As you can see I have added a url param `css` which contains the type of css stylesheet to load.

In your codebehind you can catch the value by:

```
// Create a property

private string CssSheet {
    get {
        // Check if param is defined and not null
        // If not null return value else return default style sheet
        return Request["css"] ?? "default"; 
    }
}
```